# Python Pyserial Write command not sending without delay

Tags: python, pyserial

I am using the Python Pyserial library to communicate with my computer serial port.
I am trying to write a command as quickly as possible through the Uart. The problem I am having is the write function won't send unless I have a delay of 0.5 secs after the write function and I am not sure why.

```
ON = ":00000008f8"
OFF = ":00000009f7"

ser = serial.Serial(port=2,baudrate=28800)
#print ser

ser.flushInput() #flush input buffer, discarding all its contents
ser.flushOutput()#flush output buffer, aborting current output
             #and discard all that is in buffer

print ser.isOpen() #True

ser.write(ON)
ser.write(OFF)
#time.sleep(0.5)   

#Close port
ser.close()
print ser.isOpen()
```

Comment: Is this the complete code?

Comment: Edited my code slightly, If I add a delay only the ON command executes but not the off command

Comment: Is it not EXECUTED, or not SENT? Since it could be sent, but not received properly by the second side

Comment: how can I check if it has been sent but not executed?

Comment: Open some sort of serial terminal on the other side and see the data incoming

Comment: I can't do because if using something like realTerm, then python can no longer ascess the port

Comment: You need it on the other side of your serial link. The machine you are sending to. Run the terminal instead of you receiving application

Comment: I've just did it for you, but with python3, slightly modifing your code to match it, and tested with virtual serial pair (com0com). Received both strings fully.

Comment: can you explain how to use a virtual port com0com

Comment: Just read it's page. In short, it is a driver capable of creating pairs of virtual COM ports connected with virtual serial cable (null-modem cable). Such that once you are writing to one of them, you are able to receive on the second one. It is very useful for debugging serial protocols with single machine even without physical ports available.

Comment: Thanks, getting com0com on window 8.1 was a little tricky. you are right, virtually port is doing exactly what I ask. but I think the problem I have is the serial port buffer are being filled to quickly and this problem is not simulate well with a virtual port

Comment: What hardware device are you talking to? try adding a long delay after the initial connection.